# pip install error on some packages, but not others

Tags: python

"ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyterlabs (from versions: none)ERROR: No matching distribution found for jupyterlabs"

for context I just followed this video to solve sucessfully "pip is not recognized as an internal or external command" immediately post python install - by editing "system environment variables" (search for in windows menu) -- where I added path directory to python. idk exactly why i needed to do this, though maybe it'll help you help me

Comment: bro its `jupyterlab` not jupyterlabs. run `pip install jupyterlab` as mentioned in the [docs](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html) here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.